# Formating decimal on fly on a TextField iOS7 Xcode5

Tags: ios7, decimal, textfield

I need to achieve this:

When user types (on a textField): 123456

the field will show 123,456

I have the code below, but, for some reason I can figure it out when I type "5" the whole field is reseted to 1.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
NSString *textt = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSString *formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[textt floatValue]]];


textField.text = formattedString;


return NO;

}
```

Comment: because after the comma `,` is added and the `[textt floatValue]` converts the string __(!)__ `1,234` to `1`, regarding the conversion happens until the parser reaches the first non-valid numeric character... that is why you get `1`, (which is literally always the very first number you typed).

Comment: and how can I fix that? I don't want it to reset after the comma appears. I want to continue to I can get numbers like 12,345

Comment: you just need to parse your string back to number.

Comment: Like this, right:     textt = [textt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

Comment: yes, if you are sure that you are not using any another formatter/locales in your app, that hardcoded version could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does the job for you, shame on me I could have done it better, but I hope someone can give you a more elegant solution for this issue. (e.g. using regexp or something)

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSNumberFormatter *_formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSMutableString *_pureNumber = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]];
    [_pureNumber replaceOccurrencesOfString:_formatter.groupingSeparator withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, _pureNumber.length)];
    [textField setText:[_formatter stringFromNumber:@([_pureNumber doubleValue])]];
    return NO;
}
```

---

so, the general idea is you need to convert back your `textt` to a number.

the auto-parser cannot do it for you, becasue the after `1,234` the `1,2345` is not a valid number in this formatter, that is why you have got the very first number only, simply the parser chucks everything after the comma `,` away. (that is a `groupingSeparator` in this formatter).